# Changing a displayed list asynchronously from a radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have a WPF application with the property DisplayListType bound to a RadioButton. Selecting the radio button will change the displayed list by calling MakePatientList() which is asynchronous. When MakePatientList() is finished, it updates the displayed list of DxList but I see no reason to await it in the ListTypes property. However *it does need to be called* to set the DxList property, as shown below. (Note: Visual Studio complains if I do not put
await in the property setter where MakePatientList() is started).

The *await* in ListTypes is clearly wrong. How can this be done?

TIA
(Visual studio 2015, .NET 4.6.1)

```
 private ListTypes displayListType;
        public  ListTypes DisplayListType
        {
            get { return displayListType; }
            set
            {
                displayListType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DisplayListType");

                switch (value)
                {
                    case ListTypes.ActiveDiagnosis:
                        await MakePatientList();  <---WRONG??
                        break;
                    .......
                }
            }
        }

private async Task MakePatientList()
        {
            // consume the WCF service.
            var result = await MedicalClient.GetActiveDxAsync(Encounter.PatientRecid, (DateTime)Encounter.Tencounter);

            dxlist = result.Select(r =>
                                new ViewDx
                                {
                                    Cdesc = r.Cdesc,
                                    Code = r.Code,
                                    Chronic = r.Chronic
                                })
                            .ToList();

            DxList = new ObservableCollection<ViewDx>(dxlist);
        }

private ObservableCollection<ViewDx> dxList;
        public ObservableCollection<ViewDx> DxList
        {
            get { return dxList; }

            set
            {
                if (dxList != value)
                {
                    dxList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DxList");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an [article on async data-binding in MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) that may be helpful.

In particular, the `DxList` should be an "asynchronous" data-bound property. Using the updated [`NotifyTask` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs), it would look something like this:

```
NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<ViewDx>> DxList { get; set { with notify } }
```

And updated as such:

```
private async Task<ObservableCollection<ViewDx>> MakePatientListAsync()
{
  var result = await MedicalClient.GetActiveDxAsync(Encounter.PatientRecid, (DateTime)Encounter.Tencounter);

  dxlist = result.Select(r =>
      new ViewDx
      {
        Cdesc = r.Cdesc,
        Code = r.Code,
        Chronic = r.Chronic
      })
      .ToList();

  return new ObservableCollection<ViewDx>(dxlist);
}

public  ListTypes DisplayListType
{
  get { return displayListType; }
  set
  {
    displayListType = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("DisplayListType");

    switch (value)
    {
      case ListTypes.ActiveDiagnosis:
        DxList = NotifyTask.Create(() => MakePatientListAsync());
        break;
      .......
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `DxList.Result` now contains the observable collection (so you'll need to update your listbox bindings). There's also other properties hanging off `DxList` such as `DxList.IsNotCompleted` that you can data-bind to for enabling/disabling controls and/or showing/hiding loading spinners.